# UWP Write to CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, io, uwp

I'm trying to write down my dataset into a csv file with the following code

```
 const string filePath = @"F:\train\data.csv";

  foreach (var i in _trainingList)
        {
            var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", i.Item1, i.Item2, i.Item3);
            _csv.AppendLine(newLine);
        }
  Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //TODO unauthorized exception
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, _csv.ToString());
        });
```

I get an *System.UnauthorizedAccessException*, I have checked that the file allows reading and writing.

Is the problem arising because I'm using UWP platform and does not support the operation. or is my code erroneous?

Comment: Do you have the file open when running the code?

Comment: Where is `_csv` defined?

Comment: @krillgar No, it's not open.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It's defined as an attribute in the class, I check the values and it seems correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access files in the user's Download folder that were created by your application. It's likely that `F:\train` is not that folder.

See this MSDN article for what folders a UWP (or Windows Store) app can access: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx